# R: Looping logic to calculate a moving sum over 30 days

Tags: r, loops, group-by

I have several accounts, and I am trying to calculate a moving 30 day sum of amounts deposited, grouped by account. i would like to do 31 iterations of this calculation. So there will be 31 sums for each account, representing a 30 day period of summed deposit amounts.

For example, the first iteration is deposits from 10/1 to 10/30, second iteration is 10/2 to 10/31.... then eventually 11/1 to 11/30, for example.

My first thought is to do two loops, with a group by account sum calculations.

here is some sample data, two accounts, 10 and 11. With deposit amounts for days 1 through 61.

```
x <- data.frame(day = c(1:61),
                account = ifelse(runif(61) <.5, 10, 11),
                amount = rnorm(61,mean = 100, sd = 10))

numinterations<-31
numsumdays<-30

monthsums<- for(i in 1:ndays){
              for(i in 1:numsumdays){
                 sum(testloop$daily_total) group by account
              }  


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rollapply` from `zoo` to apply a moving window to the column. As per request, I avoided the use of `dplyr`. Instead, the data frame is split into a list of data frames, that is recombined at the end.

I clunkily had to fill in the missing day/account combinations here first though for it to work; probably there is a more elegant way to do that.

```
library(zoo)

x <- data.frame(day = c(1:61),
            account = ifelse(runif(61) <.5, 10, 11),
            amount = rnorm(61,mean = 100, sd = 10))

all_combinations <- expand.grid(day=unique(x$day),account=unique(x$account))
x <- merge(x, all_combinations, all=TRUE)
x[is.na(x)] <- 0

lx <- split(x, x$account)
for (account in names(lx)) {
  lx[[account]][['rollingSum']] <- rollapply(lx[[account]][['amount']], width=30, FUN=sum, partial=TRUE, align='right')
}
names(lx) <- NULL
x <- do.call(rbind, lx)
```

Comment: the clunkiness is fine, the real data would be fully occupied. what about a solution not using dplyr? I am not sure how to apply that rollapply function to other grouping functions

Comment: I edited the solution so dplyr is no longer required. If you want to use aggregation functions that are not standard, simply write your own and provide its name to the FUN argument. As long as it takes a vector of values as its input and has a single value as its output, it should work.

Comment: It looks like the sum is going backwards, so from the output, day 1 rolling sum for account 10 should be 117.099, not 1343. But i see that for day 61, the correct sums are being added up going back in time

Comment: The numbers are randomly generated so I can't compare those; do you mean that for Day 1, you want the sum up to and including Day1 instead? Right now it looks 30 days ahead of Day 1. Of course at the end it doesn't have enough days available ahead, so it treats them as 0 then. You can reverse this behavior by using `align='right'` (I edited it)